# Rails - Mail_form how to automatically set "from" field to current_user email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contact-form, mail-form

I followed this guide https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/rails-4-simple-form-and-mail-form-to-make-contact-form/

In the contact form,  the user fills out a field for their name and email along with the message.

```
class ContactForm < MailForm::Base

  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "My Contact Form",
      :to => "FILLTHISIN@example.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

I want to automatically send from the `user.email` attribute and not have the user fill out a field.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trh this:

In your, `app/views/contacts/new.html.erb` make `email field` as `hidden field` and use `current_user.email` as `value` of `hidden email field` should work.

Note: I am assuming you are using `Devise` gem

Comment: I am using Devise but I am getting this message `undefined local variable or method `current_user' for ContactForm:Class`

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. We can not use "current_user" method in model. Instead, In “app/views/contacts/new.html.erb” make email field as hidden field and use current_user.email as value of hidden email field should work.